# jquery content slider, control speed?

Tags: jquery, slider

I am using a very light jquery content slider but have no idea how to control the speed of the animation. It's currently very fast and I need to slow it down. I'm afraid that jquery is a new area for me and despite trying several ways I can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreiated. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#button a').click(function(){
        var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('#myslide .cover').animate({left:-960*(parseInt(integer)-1)})
        $('#button a').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            if($(this).hasClass('button'+integer)){
                $(this).addClass('active')
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#myslide .cover').animate({left:-960*(parseInt(integer)-1)});

 //change to
                                                                 //speed in ms
 $('#myslide .cover').animate({left:-960*(parseInt(integer)-1)}, 1000);
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/ here the .animate jQuery syntax. 1000ms == 1 second, change the number to taste.

Comment: Superb. So simple. Thank you.

Comment: It kept counting down saying 'you can accept this in 5 mins'! I've done it now. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a parameter to [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), for example :

```
.animate({left:-960*(parseInt(integer)-1)},5555)
```

the css will be got after 5555 milliseconds.

Comment: Superb. So simple. Thank you.